# Code of conduct

Tags: discussion, bible

Recently, while posting messages to the "Super User" and "Server Fault" Stack Exchange sites, the moderators summarily edited out the phrases "Thank you ( see Colossians 3:15, for example )" and "Sincerely in Christ," which were included in my posts.  Will that happen here?

Comment: It's [common practice on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950) to remove salutations, thank yous, and greetings from posts since they distract from the main content and make the site less usable for people who browse the site looking for quick answers. This site specifically seems to be more lenient, but your taglines are pretty excessive.

Comment: @Russell. Looking at your other questions, it seems that what was removed was not just "thank you" and "sincerely" but also admonitions to go and read specific parts of the Bible. Those count as advertizing and , speaking personally as a Christian, I find them counterproductive and support their removal.

Comment: I would just like to kindly mention that the word "Christian" is a religious reference.  Since you mentioned it, though, I will kindly mention that there is no such thing as a denominational Christian.  This network's claim of avoiding religious references seems to be falling apart at the seams.

Answer (score 7):

All manner of "thank you" and "sincerely"s are edited away all throughout the Stack Exchange network as they are not seen as necessary or useful here.

But if you'd like to encourage people to read a particular Bible verse or two, you could put it in your profile description (the "about me" box.)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [curiousdannii answered](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6568/30) which is spot on as far as tag lines of all sorts being generally rejected in SE sites across the board, it also bears noting specifically that this is not a forum. I see [you've used that word in some removed tag-lines](https://serverfault.com/posts/919245/revisions) (including from [the above question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/65543/revisions) in reference to this site). SE sites are not forums, they are not for discussion or social back and forth. As such the feature set and site "norms" specifically avoid anything that encourages or feels like that sort of interaction. The sites are question and answer sites, and each post is question with direct answers, not a forum with discussion threads.

Thoroughly groking this difference will make it a lot easier to use the site appropriately. Anything that doesn't make questions clearer or answers more direct probably doesn't belong. You can use your profile to say a bit about yourself or even forward an agenda, but if your purpose in writing posts is to get people to visit your personal sites or read a verse or change their minds about some issue then this is probably not the site for you.

Comment: If you will kindly click on the "StackExchange" icon at the upper left-hand corner of this web page, you will see that part of the purpose of this network of communities is to "learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers."  It would be impossible to accomplish those stated goals without "social back and forth" as you stated above.  I would also like to kindly add that even if you were on a remote island by yourself, you could still engage in social back and forth by speaking with yourself.

Comment: @Russell Oh please, lets not be pedantic. Do you want to learn about how this site works and the local culture norms or do you want to try to argue to change them? We're willing to help with the former, but before you do that nobody is going to be very open to the latter. Of course some back and forth happens, but the point of these sites is that the _emphasis_ is on the content, not the personalities. That's what makes the sites popular in the first place: the high signal to noise ratio. Your argument (and examples of your tag lines) are noise that detract from the main point of the post.